# Name this children's sci fi show from my childhood

Tags: tv, names, story-identification

I am trying to remember what this show was from when I watched it in my childhood (I grew up in the 90's).

It was a sci-fi television series with a crew of children/young adults that were stranded in space on their ship. They spend the series trying to find a way back home. Just before I stopped watching it for whatever reason, they crash-landed in a jungle - whether it was on earth or not, I do not know...maybe it was part of the suspense.

I remember two characters:
-A humanistic female android.

-A guy with ears shaped like spirals. He had excellent hearing. I remember this because in one episode the android was stuck in quicksand and he could hear her muffled cries.

I remember two episodes:
-One involved the crew encountering a sort of doppleganger crew. They appeared in a similar ship and offered assistance, or something like that. The real crew left after they sensed the other crew had less than good intentions.

-The other episode was the aforementioned plane crash in the jungle. I believe it was the same episode with the android almost suffocating in quick sand (children's show logic).

It was probably on nickelodeon, but I could be way off there. I keep thinking the title is "lost in space" but clearly that's a different show.

Comment: The episode was the one with "9stine".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Space Cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Cases)

Produced by Nickoleodeon

This show featured exactly the crew you describe.
Radu is the spiral ear guy, he can hear very well and is "super strong".
There is a female android named Thelma.
A girl from Mercury named Rosie.
The main character "Harlan Band" is from Earth.
A girl from Saturn with her alternate personality (Catalina and Suzee)
Then there's Davinport and Goddard, their teachers, (Davinport and Goddard do the best they can, it's Spaaaaaaa-aaaaa-aace Cases).

Bova was the clear star of the show.

They are a crew of cadets who get stranded in space and have to find their way home.

Comment: Beat me to it - I will add that the episode with the duplicate crew members is called 'Trouble With Doubles' and the one with quicksand is called 'New Places, New Faces'. A fan site with descriptions of episodes can be found at http://www.spacecasestv.com/